# Proving a set has a convergent subsequence under infinite norm

Tags: real-analysis

Here's the problem:

> Let $\{g_n \}_\mathbb{N} \subset C([a,b])$ be such that $|g_n(x) |\leq 1$ for all $x \in [a,b]$ and for all $n \in \mathbb{N}.$ Show that $ \{ H_n(x)= \int_a^x g_n(t) \ dt\}_{\mathbb{N}}$ contains a $d_{\infty}$-convergent subsequence.

Here $\{g_n \}_\mathbb{N}$ denotes a sequence of bounded continuous functions on the interval $[a,b]$. Also $d_\infty$ denotes the infinite norm, that is, for two functions $f$ and $g$:

$$d_\infty(f,g) = \sup_{a \leq x \leq b} |f(x)-g(x)|.$$

To solve the problem,I'm trying to prove that the set $H = \{ H_n(x)= \int_a^x g_n(t) \ dt\}_{\mathbb{N}}$ is compact and thus contains a $d_{\infty}$-convergent subsequence. To prove that it is a compact set I'm using a version of the Arzela-Ascoli Theorem which states that a set A is compact if and only if the set is bounded, closed and uniformly equicontinuous.

I have proved that $H$ is bounded and uniformly equicontinuous, but I'm stuck on the closed set part. Normally I take a convergent sequence within the set and see if it converges to a point contained in the set, however I'm not being able to prove this here.

How could one prove that $H$ is a closed set (if it even is closed)?

Also, is this a correct approach to solving the problem?

Comment: In infinite dimensional spaces, closed and bounded $\not \implies$ compact.

Comment: @Rebellos The question does not make that implication. I'm even referring to a specific theorem, namely the Arzelà-Ascoli Theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conclusion is that $H$ is relatively compact (equivalently, every sequence has  a convergent subsequence), not that it is compact. You cannot prove that $H$ is closed. For example, if $g_n(x)=\frac 1 n$ then $H$ is not closed.

Comment: Thank you. Does this convergent subsequence converge to an element of $H$?

Comment: @ThomasBladt In my example the limit does not belong to $H$.